# how to specify commit in docker-compose remote github build

Tags: git, docker, github, build, docker-compose

I want to build services using `Dockerfiles` in remote projects found on github. This is for an end-to-end testing framework, so I need to be able to specify specific commits I want it to build. I am having a lot of difficulty trying to figure out how to pull a specific commit.

I have a docker compose file which looks something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: https://${GITHUB_ACCESS}:@github.com/mycompany/web.git#${COMMIT_SHA}
```

The above works fine if I omit `#${COMMIT_SHA}`. Unfortunately, if I include the sha for the specific commit I care about, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: error fetching: error: no such remote ref <commit sha>
: exit status 128
```

I am certain the sha exists, and I have tried it with a few others just to be sure. Am I getting the syntax wrong here, or does docker-compose not support referring to a specific commit?

Comment: The docs only mention using branches and tags for builds using github repos as their build context. Maybe worth a shot tagging the specific commit in git and using it as the reference instead of the commit SHA. 
Have a look here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories
and here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3038

Comment: Does the URL work in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you get err `ERROR: error fetching: error: no such remote ref <commit sha>: exit status 128` then most certainly you have syntax issue. In your case you have few possible causes.

- `GITHUB_ACCESS` || `GIT_COMMIT_SHA` environment variable is not set
- `GIT_COMMIT_SHA` is set to invalid `sha` value.

  > I am certain the sha exists

  Just double check

You can configure Git URLs in their fragment section separated by a colon `:`. The first part represents the reference that Git will check out, this can be either a branch, a tag, or a commit SHA. So yes `docker-compose` does support referring to a specific commit. The second part represents a sub directory inside the repository that will be used as a build context. This is only needed when your docker file is not in repository root. Valid Git URL schemas can be anything what Git considers natively as valid. See this [file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77bd3ea9f54f1584147b594abc04c26ca516d987/t/t0110-urlmatch-normalization.sh) found in its core for reference.

- If your `Dockerfile` is not in repository root you would get `ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile`

I'm using [nginxinc/docker-nginx](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx) repository as example. There are multiple docker files in this repository, so let's say we want to build image based on `Dockerfile` found in repository subdirectory `stable/alpine`

**Example 1**

In this example lets build docker image from `master` branch

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: web:latest
    build: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx.git#master:stable/alpine
```

**Example 1 - Do build it based on specific commit**

I add `.env` file while most likely your variables are set in your Continuous Integration environment.

```
GIT_COMMIT_SHA=d377983a14b214fcae4b8e34357761282aca788f
```

and change our `docker-compose.yaml` to

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: web:${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}
    build: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx.git#${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}:stable/alpine
```

here resulting `build:` url should be `https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx.git#d377983a14b214fcae4b8e34357761282aca788f:stable/alpine`